# Why Chrome driver not opening while as a NUnit project, but works fine in a Console App with Nuget packages added?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have created a Console App (.NET Framework) project in my Visual Studio, added all the required packages (NUnit, Test3Adapter, Selenium) and gave the local path of my chrome.exe, and the test is running.

But, if I create an NUnit Test project (.NET Core), add all Nuget packages required and try to run my tests, I get the error stating that:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service
>   on http://localhost:/

For running my script through Azure DevOps, it's advised to use NUnit project rather than having it as Console application.

Note:

1. I tried adding the chrome.exe path after manually downloading it and also tried adding chrome through Nuget Packets (Both `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` or `Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver`). Nothing worked.
2. Irrespective of running in GUI or headless mode, I get the same error

Sample code:

```
IWebDriver driver;

[SetUp]
public void startBrowser()
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
}

[Test]
public void test()
{
    driver.Url = "http://www.google.co.in";
}

[TearDown]
public void closeBrowser()
{
    driver.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing just using `new ChromeDriver()` and leave out the path? I have ChromeDriver installed using NuGet and I don't supply a path and it just works.

Comment: I tried this way too.  Added Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver as Nuget package, but I'm hit with DriverServiceNotFoundException.  Once after rebuilding the solution, I'm able to see the chrome.exe file added to my directory (C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Test_Folder_Automation\NUnitTest_App\NUnitTest_App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1).  Still without giving the path or mentioning CurrentDirectory, I get driver not found exception.